# Javascript: Creating a custom object from string

Tags: javascript

I have a string of comma separated values. As below:

```
var myValues = "Ip1, Ip2, Ip3";
```

I want to convert this to a custom object. The result should be:

```
 {
  Input: 'Ip1',
  Output: 'Ip1_Updated'    
 },
 { 
  Input: 'Ip2',
  Output: 'Ip2_Updated'
 },
 { 
  Input: 'Ip3',
  Output: 'Ip3_Updated'
 }
```

What is the best way to approach this. 
Can I split on "," and then loop through the string and create custom array

Comment: why not try your idea (split on ",", then loop) first?

Comment: *Can I split on "," and then loop through the string and create custom array*. Yes, you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split an then use the function `map`

```js
var myValues = "Ip1, Ip2, Ip3",
    result = myValues.split(",").map(s => ({ Input: s.trim(), Output: `${s.trim()}_Updated` }));
 
 console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another alternative, is preparing the data and then convert to the desired structure:

```js
var myValues = "Ip1, Ip2, Ip3",
    split = myValues.split(","),
    preparedData = split.map(str => str.trim()),
    result = preparedData.map(ip => ({ Input: ip, Output: `${ip}_Updated` }));
 
 console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It'd be cleaner to use an additional map step to trim things: `.split(',').map(x => trim...).map(...)`

Comment: @georg two loops?

Comment: @Ele I have another question which is related to this mapping json. Would appreciate if you can look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556448/knockout-js-creating-json-from-viewmodel-observable-array

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split()` and `map()`:

```js
var myValues = "Ip1, Ip2, Ip3";
myValues = myValues.split(',').map(function(i){
  return {Input: i.trim(), Output: i.trim() + '_Updated'};
});

console.log(myValues);
```